# Delete Divs from HTML codes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a working times app and you can enter and save something. I also programmed that the times are saved. I created a button that should delete the divs, but it doesn't work.

```js
myWorkingHours.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('html');

function deleteWorktime() {
  let deleteDivContainer = document.getElementById("myWorkingHours");
  myWorkingHours.addEventListener("click", () => {
    myWorkingHours.remove();
  })
}

function addWorktime() {

  let currentDate = myDate.value;
  let startTime = myStartTime.value;
  let endTime = myEndTime.value;

  myWorkingHours.innerHTML +=
    `<div class="list-item">
    <img class="small-img" src="img/Uhr.png">
    ${currentDate} ${startTime} - ${endTime} 
    </div>`;

  localStorage.setItem('html', myWorkingHours.innerHTML);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Roboto";
}

#addbutton {
  background-color: rgb(7, 158, 240);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#deletebutton {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
}

.list-item {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: 60;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.small-img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Arbeitszeiten</h1>
<input id="myDate" placeholder="Datum einfügen" type="date">
<input id="myStartTime" placeholder="Startzeit einfügen" type="time">
<input id="myEndTime" placeholder="Endzeit einfügen" type="time">
<button id="addbutton" onclick="addWorktime()">Speichern</button>
<button id="deletebutton" onclick="deleteWorktime">Arbeitszeiten löschen</button>
<div id="myWorkingHours">
</div>
```

I tried deleting the file with a remove child and remove

Comment: You haven't called the delete function: `onclick="deleteWorktime"`; it needs parentheses to execute it.

Comment: Also, your script has an error because you never define the `myWorkingHours ` variable.

Comment: Also, deleteWorktime() only adds a click listener... you would need to click the button AND then the myWorkingHours element to make it remove?